# AWS ec2 instances clusters and ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a **non-EKS** AWS kubernetes cluster with 1 master 3 worker nodes

I am trying to install **nginx ingress controller** in order to use the cluster with a domain name but unfortunately it does not seem to work, the **nginx ingress controller service** is not taking automatically an IP and even if I set manually an **external IP** this IP is not answering in 80 port.

Comment: Could you share if you have an any AWS drivers for your k8s deployment and the ingress config? If you just have an "ordinary" k8s, aws doesn't necessarily allow `taking automatically an IP`.

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you for your answer, no I do not have any special drivers for my deployments I have setup a k8s cluster with flannel plugin

Comment: Just to make it clear- you are running kubernetes cluster in cloud bootstraped using kubeadm and you want to expose your application externally?

Comment: @MariuszK. Yes I have 3 EC2 instances that are in the same subnet I have configured their services correctly using kubeadm but both backend and frontend services can be accessed only ADDRESS_IP:PORT

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a public domain . Expose the nginx-ingress deployment(service) as a loadbalancer which will create an ALB.
You can then route the domain name to the ALB Alias in R53

Comment: Do you mean to  expose as a loadbalancer through a service?

Comment: Better write your comment answers in this section ok I will try to expose the nginx-ingress contoller deployment. And after that ? Must I apply the ingress yaml cluster?

Comment: See you will deploy a nginx ingress controller . Then expose the deployment as a service  with type =loadbalancer. So now your ingress is publicly accessible.
To expose app sepcific custom endpoints add it  as ingress rules.
Hope Im clear

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `External IP` remaining in pending is that there is no load balancer in front of your cluster to provide it with external IP, like it would work EKS. You can achieve it by boostraping your cluster with `--cloud-provider` option using `kubeadm`.

You can follow these tutorials on how to successfully achieve it:

[Kubernetes, Kubeadm, and the AWS Cloud Provider](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/02/18/kubernetes-kubeadm-and-the-aws-cloud-provider/)

[Setting up the Kubernetes AWS Cloud Provider](https://blog.heptio.com/setting-up-the-kubernetes-aws-cloud-provider-6f0349b512bd)

[Kubernetes: part 2 — a cluster set up on AWS with AWS cloud-provider and AWS LoadBalancer](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-part-2-a-cluster-set-up-on-aws-with-aws-cloud-provider-and-aws-loadbalancer-f02c3509f2c2)

Comment: Thank you I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different solutions to that.. my favorite solution is

- Use an Ingress Controller like the ingress-nginx (there are multiple different Ingress Controllers available for Kubernetes, a very good comparison is provided [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191WWNpjJ2za6-nbG4ZoUMXMpUK8KlCIosvQB0f-oq3k/edit#gid=907731238))
- Configure the IngressController Service to use NodePort and use a port like 30080
- Create an own AWS ALB with Terraform for an example and add the NodePort 30080 to the TargetGroup
- Create a Ingress resource to configure the IngressController

The whole traffic flow could look like that:

[image: Traffic Flow]

If you still have some questions, just ask them here :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you will have to expose the deployment as a service
kubectl expose deployment {deploymentname} -n ns ==type=Loadbalancer --name={name}